# Android SwipeToDismiss ListView messes up Items

Tags: android, listview

i use this **SwipeToDismissListener** to dismiss items in a listview.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/UI/gridview/com_datayumyum_posSwipeDismissListViewTouchListener_java.htm

The dismissing works fine and also returns the correct dismiss positions, but afterwards things are starting to get strange for me.

In onDismiss, i remove the item from my adapter:

```
public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {                
    for (int i: reverseSortedPositions) {
                Item item = adapter.getItem(i);
                adapter.remove(item);
            }
}
```

When the **ListView** is redrawed now, items start to look like other items in the list ( so Item A displays the text of Item B) but if I implement an **onClickListener** and check what item it actually is, it is the correct one, so it is clearly a **graphical** issue.

I can fix this wrong look by calling **adapter.notifydatasetchanged** 2 times independently on an item click....
It does not work with adapter.notifydatasetchanged if I just call it once or if i call it delayed but automatically...

Does someone have an Idea what is happening here?

Additionally I noticed, that my **adapter.getView** is called multiple times for each item if only one redraw should happen, don't know if this is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself.
It was simply a bad implementation of view recycling in the ArrayAdapter.
So, just as a tip, if you remove elements from a list at runtime, make sure to do a good implementation of the View recycling in getView.